# WordPress causing animation to overflow

Tags: javascript, css, html, wordpress, adobe-edge

I am working on a website and added an animation of clouds flowing using adobe edge animation.

http://avuedesigns.com/iaq/

I have created a thread over at the adobe community (http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1128782) and it seems that my code to make it responsive, and the overflow are correctly setup.

So basically I have no idea why WordPress is either breaking it. Or why my little bit of code thinks the website is wider than it really is. Maybe fresh eyes can see something I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct your container has an overflow attribute most likely set to scroll within your css file.

set this to;

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, wordpress is just a cms engine that spits out html - it is hardly to blame.  I do see that the width keeps changing and the horiz scroll bar appears and disappears which is definitely not optimal.

I think the starting place is with the main container div....do you have overflow:hidden set?  This should allow your clouds to appear outside of the visible pane without forcing the div to change width.